# Javascript - Function wont run from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function called `this.create()`

```
this.create = function() {
  var validate = this.validate();

  if (validate === false) {
    return;

  } else if (document.getElementById("nameID").value == "") {

    alert("Enter an ID");
  } else {
    this.runMapping();

    $.post('http://*************', {

    }, function(data) {

      var results = $.parseJSON(data);

      if (results.status == "fail") {
        alert('FAILED');
      } else {
        ID = (results.data[0].nameID);

        alert("SUCCESS");
        this.setDate();


      }
    });
  }
}
```

And another function called `this.setDate()`:

```
this.setDate = function() {
  alert("In date");

  $.get('http:**********',
    function(data) {
      var results = $.parseJSON(data);
      date = (results.data[0].date);
      return;
    }
  )
}
```

Now, if I put `this.setDate()` on its own button it works fine, but it refuses to run when `this.create()` is called, even though `alert("SUCCESS")` is alerted in the `this.create()` function.

I should add that I am relativity new to JS, so please excuse me if this is an easy mistake I am making. I also note that `this.runMapping()` is working fine in `this.create()`.

Comment: In your callback function, `this` refers to the callback function, not to the outer object. Use an arrow function, or use a variable to hold a reference to the outer object.

Comment: Or dont work with the context at all if possible. And please have a look at your consope, it will say something like "cannot call `undefined` at..."

Comment: Thank you guys, that was the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `this` is now  context of the function where you are calling your `this.setDate();` and there is no such function in it.

Use arrow function or save `this` reference to a variable and call your function what that reference like

```
var that = this;
 this.create = function() {
   ....
    that.setDate()
   ...
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. Of course! I was thinking, this was the class! Thank you George!